# on windows . i cant find nmake.exe in my microsoft vs 8

Tags: elixir, nmake

```
bcrypt_elixir
```

> could not compile dependency :bcrypt_elixir, "mix compile" failed. You can recompile this dependency with "mix deps.compile bcrypt_elixir", update it with "mix deps.update bcrypt_elixir" or clean it with "mix deps.clean bcrypt_elixir"

```
tc_api
```

> (Mix) "nmake" not found in the path. If you have set the MAKE environment variable,
> please make sure it is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Please read the requirement [here](https://github.com/riverrun/comeonin/wiki/Requirements). You need to install Visual Studio to use [nmake.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/nmake-reference?view=vs-2019). For older VS version, like VS 2008, you can [read this answer](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/47088e34-8bd5-4b8d-a4c3-61a1356476c2/run-nmake-in-windows-server-2008?forum=msbuild).

However, you can install [Windows Subsystem Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10) (WSL) so you can install all dependencies and tools that available on Linux, including gcc, make and glibc easily. You can install Erlang, Elixir, and everything you need on WSL, and code them on your favourite IDE on Windows.

Comment: And how exactly would said IDE run build tools, code checkers, etc. on WSL environment if it does not explicitly support WSL?

Comment: @dualed you can compile things and run Elixir on WSL terminal

Comment: That is not what an IDE is for. The `I` is for integrated, if you run everything separately then it's not integrated anymore and the IDE cannot annotate errors, resolve types, etc.

Comment: @dualed There is no IDE for Elixir that I know of.  So, ok, you won't have an IDE but it'll all work.